# Considering rescinding my accepted job offer

Tags: new-job, job-change

I need extra sets of eyes on my situation. I’m leaning towards rescinding my acceptance of a job offer, but I am not sure if these are really red flags, or if I’m looking for problems because I’m ambivalent about leaving my current job.

Background: I started interviewing with a company at the end of June. They were very slow in the process and at first I thought I was a backup candidate, but it really seems like this is just how they operate. The position is a career growth for me and I enjoyed everyone I met with. When the offer came through, it was a significant raise. So better comp, a higher title, more challenges, and people I like? Accepting was a no brainer! They gave me a start date of one month from my date of acceptance, which I was fine with. Gives me plenty of opportunity to tie off all open items at existing job (which I have enjoyed for the most part), and then take a few days off to rest before the new job starts. I am excited for the new opportunity but have very mixed emotions about leaving my current team and company.

But I’ve gotten silence from them since my offer was presented and I am beginning to consider these red flags. Overall, I’m not going to get bent out of shape because HR is ignoring my questions about benefits, or that IT asked me about what kind of equipment I wanted but hasn’t responded to either of my follow up emails asking a clarifying question. They did reach out to ask about an i9, so I assume everything is still on track. But the biggest concern is that I have not heard one word from the hiring manager since my interview. Seems very unusual that he didn’t reach out to welcome me to the team. He was copied on a question HR had for me on my background. He didn’t respond to that thread. I gave it two weeks and sent him an email, stating that I’m excited to be joining the team and asked if there is anything he would like me to prepare or review for my first day. Not one word.

This is a 100% remote role, and if my manager won’t engage with me now, what will happen when something is wrong? I am considering rescinding and asking my current employer to reconsider my resignation.

Am I looking for issues where none exist, or is this a genuine concern?

Comment: Have you actually tried to engage with your manager? You mentioned HR, the hiring manager, and the IT group. Are any of those your actual manager? Also, have you considered that they may be very busy with their day to day jobs and replying to emails from a newly hired employee has simply fallen through the cracks? Have you considered that maybe they're just not good at HR stuff? What else does your gut tell you? As it stands, none of what you've stated stands out in particular as a red flag to me.

Comment: So you accepted a job offer, but without an actual signed contract? Have you tried calling them on the phone? You need to call them.

Comment: Did that company send you an official signed offer letter ? If yes, then it is official, and there is no need to worry. Your manager knows that you won't join the company until 1 month from now. So, maybe, he is busy with more critical tasks at work. Maybe, he thinks that for now, HR and IT would be your first contact points.

Comment: Also, in all the jobs I've worked, I've never travelled into work before my start date in order to meet the team, or spoken with my boss before my start date. Maybe there are cultures where that happens, but there are certainly cultures where it does not.

Comment: I too am struggling to see the red flags. As both a hiring manager and employee, nothing is standing out really. HR do the 'hiring' paperwork etc and your team will integrate you and onboard you from day 1 rather than day -14 as that is when you become their employee. Calls/emails with the TL is a nice to have but not essential right now as their focus will be on your workplan for when you start.

Comment: I was invited out for a team lunch (8 years ago) as I was starting in the January and it was their Christmas lunch. This was also to meet others in the office as there was other activities that was happening around then. Had it not been that time of year, it would never have happened. Great for day 1 as I knew who everyone was, but that was more relating to that time of year than an expectation that is what should happen before I started. Everything else was when I properly started.

Comment: Try this new technology.  It's called the TELEPHONE

Answer (score 12):

Congrats on your new job. Everything you mentioned has an innocuous explanation. HR may be busy. IT is doing their best. Your hiring manager is out of office or catching up with work or in a crisis or not looking out for emails from non-employees. You've already resigned your former company. There's little difference in asking to come back in 3 months, when you'll know for sure something's wrong, versus right now. Give it a chance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with issues you raised, Yes you are reading a bit too much in to the situation in my opinion

A leeway of a month means that everything can go at its pace without being a super hectic.

Perhaps its also a glance in to the future, where you will have an adequate deadlines :)

Congratulation on your new job, never look back.

P.S.
Even if things will not workout later, you may talk to your previous employer then, but I wouldn`t recommend it.